# Xamarin.Forms gradient background for Button using Custom Renderer with iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms and I want to globally make the buttons look a little nicer.

I have achieved this just fine for the Android version using a custom renderer, but I am having trouble doing the same with iOS.

When defining buttons in my XAML pages, I reference "CustomButton" instead of "Button", and then I have the following CustomButtonRenderer in my iOS app.

Most of the style changes work just fine (border radius, etc), but I cannot seem to make it render a background gradient for the button.

Here is my code so far, but the background just displays as white. How can I make it display a gradient with the text on top?

```
class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradient.Frame = Control.Layer.Bounds;
            gradient.Colors = new CGColor[]
            {
                UIColor.FromRGB(51, 102, 204).CGColor,
                UIColor.FromRGB(51, 102, 204).CGColor
            };

            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(gradient);
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB(51, 102, 204).CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;

            Control.VerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: personal suggestion to you: if you struggle with a specific platform google for the platform and what you are trying to do. since the api is extremely similar you will find your solution with ease usually :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1st)** Do not use `AddSublayer`, use `InsertSublayerBelow` so that the Z-order will be correct and your `Title` text will be on top.

**2nd)** Override `LayoutSubviews` and update your `CAGradientLayer` frame  to match your `UIButton`.

**3rd)** Enjoy your gradient:

[image]

#### Complete Example:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace AppCompatRender.iOS
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer
    {
        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            foreach (var layer in Control?.Layer.Sublayers.Where(layer => layer is CAGradientLayer))
                layer.Frame = Control.Bounds;
            base.LayoutSubviews();
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
                gradient.CornerRadius = Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                gradient.Colors = new CGColor[]
                {
                    UIColor.FromRGB(51, 102, 104).CGColor,
                    UIColor.FromRGB(51, 202, 204).CGColor
                };
                var layer = Control?.Layer.Sublayers.LastOrDefault();
                Control?.Layer.InsertSublayerBelow(gradient, layer);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Update:

If you are using iOS 10+ *with* newer version of `Xamarin.Forms`, the `Control.Bounds` during calls to `LayoutSubViews` will all be zeros. You will need to set the gradient layer `Frame` size during sets to the control's `Frame` property, i.e.:

```
public class CustomButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer
{
    public override CGRect Frame
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Frame;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Width > 0 && value.Height > 0)
            {
                foreach (var layer in Control?.Layer.Sublayers.Where(layer => layer is CAGradientLayer))
                    layer.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, value.Width, value.Height);
            }
            base.Frame = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var gradient = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradient.CornerRadius = Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
            gradient.Colors = new CGColor[]
            {
                UIColor.FromRGB(51, 102, 104).CGColor,
                UIColor.FromRGB(51, 202, 204).CGColor
            };
            var layer = Control?.Layer.Sublayers.LastOrDefault();
            Control?.Layer.InsertSublayerBelow(gradient, layer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic solution - exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nothing shows up in the button's background, just text with a white background

Comment: @Sheagorath I updated the code to reflect changes to the `Xamarin.Forms` and `iOS` 10+, see the `Update` section I added.

Comment: how should the code look like when i'm using both version of iOS i.e iOS < 10 and iOS 10+? I'm getting  "Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application." crash while using the control inside contentviews.

Comment: @Noop You would need to debug it to determine where the sigsegv is originating from, you can also test and execute code conditionally based upon the iOS runtime version,  `if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (10,0)) { ..... } `: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/projects/environment_checks/

Answer (score 0):

In the moment that OnElementChanged is called, `Control.Layer.Bounds` is completely zero'd out. In your rendered you will need to add methods to update the Gradient's Frame to match the Control.Layer's frame.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to the comment by Robert Cafazzo, I can help to slightly adjust this render so that it works correctly:

```
public class GdyBtnRendererIos : ButtonRenderer
    {
        #region Colors
        static Color rosecolor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["ClrGeneralrose"];
        static Color orangecolor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["ClrRoseOrange"];
        CGColor roseCGcolor = rosecolor.ToCGColor();
        CGColor orangeCGcolor = orangecolor.ToCGColor();
        #endregion

        CAGradientLayer gradient;

        public override CGRect Frame
        {
            get => base.Frame;
            set
            {
                if (value.Width > 0 && value.Height > 0)
                {
                    if (Control?.Layer.Sublayers != null)
                        foreach (var layer in Control?.Layer.Sublayers.Where(layer => layer is CAGradientLayer))
                            layer.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, value.Width, value.Height);
                }
                base.Frame = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
            {
                gradient.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, Frame.Width, Frame.Height);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null) return;

            gradient = new CAGradientLayer
            {
                CornerRadius = Control.Layer.CornerRadius,
                Colors = new CGColor[] { roseCGcolor, orangeCGcolor },
                StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.1, 0.5),
                EndPoint = new CGPoint(1.1, 0.5)
            };

            var layer = Control?.Layer.Sublayers.LastOrDefault();
            Control?.Layer.InsertSublayerBelow(gradient, layer);

            base.Draw(Frame);
        }
```