# Xamarin.Forms/iOS - Hidden parent controls not rendering their child with custom renderers properly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm having a `Draw` problem on my iOS renderer for a custom control that I have. This control (lets call it, `GradientFrame`) is inside a `ContentView` with `IsVisible = false`. Now the problem is upon the initialization of the control, the `Draw` method on my renderer for iOS is not being called.

Here are some key points that I noticed that lead up to my assumption:

- I tried placing a breakpoint inside the `Draw` method but it never stopped there.
- When I set the `StackLayout`'s `IsVisible = true` it works as intended and calls the `Draw` method this stopping in the breakpoint.

---

**My iOS Renderer:**

```cs
class GradientFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer {
    ...
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect) {
        base.Draw(rect);

        if (Element is GradientFrame control) {
            CAGradientLayer gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer() {
                Frame = rect,
                // i left the other stuffs out to minimize this post.
            };

            Layer.InsertSublayerBelow(gradientLayer, Layer.Sublayers.LastOrDefault());
            Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**In my .xaml page:**

```xml
<ContentView IsVisible="false"
             Opacity="0">
    <Stacklayout Scale="0">
        <custom:GradientFrame <!-- my style properties goes in here. again left out to minimize this post --> />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Incase you might wonder, On my .xaml, the `ContentView` has `Opacity="0"` and the `StackLayout` has `Scale="0"`. These are here to be used with animations in the code behind.

---

**Expectation:**

[image: Expectation]

**Reality:**

[image: Reality]

> **Note**: The top frame has the same styling properties as the one in the *Expectation* image, but the bottom frame doesn't have any and it is intended as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my approach on rendering the `GradientFrame` and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170276/xamarin-forms-gradient-background-for-button-using-custom-renderer-with-ios#answer-37173269) approach instead. So my render now looks like this:

```cs
class GradientFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer {
    public override CGRect Frame {
        get => base.Frame;
        set {
            if(value.Width > 0 && value.Height > 0) { 
                foreach(var layer in Layer.Sublayers.Where(layer => layer is CAGradientLayer)) {
                    layer.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, value.Width, value.Height);
                }
            }
            base.Frame = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == GradientFrame.StartColorProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == GradientFrame.EndColorProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == GradientFrame.DirectionProperty.PropertyName) {
            UpdateLayer();
        }
    }

    void UpdateLayer() {
        if (Element is GradientFrame control) {
            CAGradientLayer gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer() {
                // i left the other stuffs out to minimize this post.
            };

            Layer.InsertSublayerBelow(gradientLayer, Layer.Sublayers.LastOrDefault());
            Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So now instead of using the `Draw` method to render the control, the rendering procedures are now done every time the `OnElementPropertyChanged` is called (when a property has changed). Then i overrode the `Frame` of my renderer to update the `Frame` of the layer that I added.